# How to interpret the sens slope function in R with daily data?

Tags: r, statistical-significance, kendall-tau

I'm currently working with Sen's slope  calculation for from "trend" (R) 30 years of daily data. The following output:

```
z = 3.1231, n = 13508, p-value = 0.00179
alternative hypothesis: true z is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 1.558725e-05 7.568877e-05
sample estimates:
 Sen's slope 
4.595588e-05
```

I'd like understanding how to interpret this value  when I have daily data. Can I understand that Sen's slope represents the change per day?  If I want to scale this slope to represent an annual change, would I divide it by the total number of days in 30 years?

Comment: To convert from days to years, you divide by 365.25.  To convert from a rate per day to a rate per year, you multiply by 365.25.  //  The p-value is likely meaningless, because any reasonable examination of temperature trends will account for seasonality, which will be a much greater factor than the long-term trend; and it should account for strong positive serial correlation.